# Curious sequence of missing positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Here is an Olympiad problem from my country. Consider the sequence of values of 
>   $$P(n)=  \left[n+\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\right]\quad\text{for $n=1,2,\dots$}$$
>   Question asks to find $12$-th missing integer in the sequence. Here $[\cdot ]$ represents the greatest integer function.

We have that $P(1)=2$, $P(2)=4$, $P(3)=5$, $P(4)=7$ so the missing integers are $1,3,6,10\dots$

Each being increased by $1$ more than previous increment. But why does this happen? Can we explain it??

EDIT: I did the following. Let $t=n+m$. After substitution in your last inequality and some manipulation yields
$$2n < m^2 +1/4 - m \leq 2n+2$$
etc

Comment: Please check if my editing is correct.

Comment: @Robert Z after you said I noticed that they are triangular numbers but I don't see any obvious connection to triangular numbers

Answer (score 2):

Show  that the missing integers are the [triangular numbers](https://oeis.org/A000217). Since the sequence $(P(n))_n$ is  increasing, an integer $t$ is missing if and only if there is a positive integer $n$ such that
$$P(n)<t<P(n+1)$$
that is
$$n+\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}<t\leq
(n+1)+\sqrt{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2}-1.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Robert Z.I did the following.  Let $t = n+m$. After substitution in your last inequality and some manipulation yields $ 2n < m^2 +1/4 - m \leq 2n+2$ . As $1/4$ doesn't contribute much to our inequality we can ignore it and again manipulate the inequality to arrive at $\frac{m^2+m}{2}=t$ .Hence missing numbers must be triangular numbers. Is this correct

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity A bit sketchy but it seems ok.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity Do you mind to copy your proof in your question? I already copied a part of it. Just to avoid downvotes...

Comment: @ Robert Thank you